# @react-spring/web doesn't work in Next.js when @react-spring/three is set

Tags: javascript

In my next.js project, I have one component with map rotation animation using @react-spring/web and another component with 3D model animation using @react-spring/three.
Animation created with @react-spring/web doesn't work. It is based on this example https://codesandbox.io/s/cju2d?file=/package.json:336-349.
Everything worked as it should before. Stopped working after installing @react-spring/three.

The animation created with @react-spring/three works as it should.
With @react-spring/three installed, @react-spring/web doesn't work.
If you remove @react-spring/three package - @react-spring/web animation works

I can't figure out what's wrong and how to fix it.
How can I use both @react-spring (three and web) in the same project?
I would appreciate any help.

With @react-spring/three installed:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zV-prPjv5PNGrDY3UnZZOtW451Smeb6-/view?usp=sharing

Without @react-spring/three:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZyVbYFeNLpVb6y_GBAkuSpAMYZBm-cpb/view?usp=sharing

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@react-spring/three": "^9.7.3",
     "@react-spring/web": "^9.4.3",
     "@react-three/drei": "^9.76.0",
     "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.3",
     "next": "^13.4.6",
     "react": "^18.2.0",
     "react-home": "^18.2.0",
     "arrogant": "^1.49.7",
     "three": "^0.153.0"
   },
```